# Using the global object as storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, persistence

I have made an application that is receiving location data from a few web clients on regular intervals. I made a quick implementation using couchdb, but as couchdb creates a new revision for each update and the data is quite frequently updated, it consumed a lot of disk space whereas the historic data was of little significance. I looked into MongoDB instead, but as I was thinking how I could make the MongoDB implementation, I had another idea:

The global object is in the process scope, so it can be used to share data between sessions. Persistence beyond session is not required, so I dropped the database completely and stored all the data in the global object (and persisted some data for user convenience in the HTML5 localStorage using javascript). The complexity of the backend was greatly reduced, and the solution felt somewhat elegant, but I still feel like I need to take a shower...

So to my question: Are there any obvious pitfalls with this solution that I haven't thought about?

Comment: Not enough info. What are you going to use the data for? How are you going to query it? etc.

Comment: The data are stored in a hashmap, and I won't need to make any queries as I access them directly using IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats you have rediscovered memcache. (I did it twice)
If you need to store this data then you actually should to save it to db, because server app restart will erase all data from RAM. So actually is better to use memcache and asynchronous writing to db.

Comment: Thanks :P I won't need to persist the data, though, as the correct state will be regenerated after one update cycle. I was more curious about any implications with storing large amounts of data this way.

Comment: For storing large amounts of data you need to have large RAM. memcache also has db called memcacheDB that based on BarkleyDB but uses memcache mechanisms it could be a solution.